# Is it possible to find anything out about the computer/user calling your api? If so, how?

Tags: asp.net-core, api-design

I've created an api using .net core 2 and C#.  I'm wondering if there's anyway to find out information about the computer or user that called the api.  This is an internally used api so ideally I'd get the Windows user of where the api call came from, but if there's anything I can find out (like an IP address) I'd like to know how.  If this isn't possible at all, I'd like to know so I can stop looking for a solution.

Comment: You have to implement this on your client and send to your API. All your server knows is your IP.

Comment: getting information about the computer like username, hardware specific information like serial of your hard drive and so on is the job of the client that communicates with the API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The server knows only what the client chooses to tell it, typically via request headers. However, the client can also *lie*, or "spoof" these headers. So, while something like `User-Agent` may look like it might give you some info about at least the OS/browser, all of that could be completely fabricated.

Matters are even worse with an API, as clients are typically thin, and the actual programmer or whatever connecting to your API must make a conscious decision to provide you with some particular bit of information, which most won't. A web browser typically sends certain standard things without user intervention, but even then users can change or alter what is sent.

Comment: FWIW, this is one of the primary purposes of auth. If you lock the API down, then you can know exactly who or what is utilizing it. Through a sign up process, you can force the client to provide specific information you need/want.